# MaxValue does not use composed function correctly

Tags: broken-code

I used the compose operator on two functions (a vector-valued interpolated from ndsolve composed with Norm) and then passed the result to MaxValue, which works fine only if I reapply the norm. What is happening?

Raw input

```
sol = NDSolve[{v[u] == Derivative[1][r][u], Derivative[1][v][u] == {1, 1, 1}, r[0] == {0, 0, 0}, v[0] == {1, 1, 0}}, {r, v}, {u, 0, 1}][[1]]
speed = (v /. sol) /* Norm
MaxValue[speed[u], Element[u, Interval[{0, 1}]]]
```

[file](https://gist.github.com/lasergyro/700d210567ed765e2e8b5b7e70834d98)

Screenshot
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Rather than an image, post actual Mathematica code (Raw InputForm) that can be copy and pasted into a workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this confusing too. The issue has nothing to do with compose "/*". You can reproduce it any other way.

Working with regions can be a bit strange. The issue was solved when I read this line in the documentation for MaxValue:

> "For x ϵ reg, the different coordinates can be referred to
>   using Indexed[x,i]."

So you really want:

```
MaxValue[speed[Indexed[x, 1]], x ϵ Interval[{0, 1}]]
```

The logic behind this might be confusing at first, but the point is that regions can be multidimensional, so you always get a "vector" or a list of values out of them.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Interval[{0, 1}]` is a one-dimensional region, so its elements are specified as lists of coordinates having length 1:

```
Element[{0.5}, Interval[{0, 1}]]

(* True *)
```

I would not call this strange or confusing, not any more than `{1, 0}` being an element of `Disk[]` or `{0, 0, 0}` being an element of `FullRegion[3]`.

Since the `speed` function needs scalar input, something like

```
MaxValue[speed[u], Element[{u}, Interval[{0, 1}]]]

(* 3. *)
```

would be appropriate.

Comment: Both @Searke 's answer and yours solve the issue, I ended up using this form: MaxValue[speed[u], {u} [Element] Interval[{0,1}]]